# How to get an empty set if a particular condition is not met

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

The following query works fine but the problem is, it always returns a result. It never returns an empty set.

```
SELECT sum(vmin_consumed) AS vmin
FROM usageinfo
WHERE job_end_time BETWEEN '2017-03-14' AND '2017-03-30'
AND username='tytyjt'
```

If any condition is not met, it returns `NULL`. Could I make the above query return an empty result set if the second condition `(username='foo')` is not met?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM (SELECT sum(vmin_consumed) AS vmin, username
FROM usageinfo
WHERE job_end_time BETWEEN '2017-03-14' AND '2017-03-30' AND username = "foo") p where p.username = "foo"
```

Comment: But this doesn't specifically handle the second condition

Comment: Would still return the empty set if first condition fails

Answer (score 0):

You need this,

```
SELECT IFNULL(SUM(vmin_consumed), '') AS vmin
FROM usageinfo
WHERE job_end_time BETWEEN '2017-03-14' AND '2017-03-30'
AND username='tytyjt'
```

Comment: and it says : "The SUM function returns the sum of a set of values. The SUM function ignores NULL values. If no matching row found, the SUM function returns a NULL value." and that exactly what he doesn't need

Answer (score 0):

This is really a strange requirement, try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN job_end_time BETWEEN '2017-03-14' AND '2017-03-30' THEN vmin_consumed -- The first condition is here.
             ELSE null 
        END) AS vmin
FROM usageinfo
GROUP BY username
HAVING username = 'tytyjt' -- The second condition is here.
```

I have to admit this will cause performance issue when you have big data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT _TABLE.VMIN FROM (SELECT SUM(vmin_consumed) AS VMIN
FROM usageinfo
WHERE job_end_time BETWEEN '2017-03-14' AND '2017-03-30' AND _TABLE.username =   'tytyjt') 
_TABLE
WHERE _TABLE.VMIN IS NOT NULL
```